# In Visio Addin, the API method Application.Documents.OpenEx() throw exception after opening several files (one after the other and not in parallel)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, office-addins, visio

I'm trying to open some files(between 50-400) in programmatically way by Add-in in orde to edit them.
I do this in sequential way, open one, edited, closed and so on.

Sometimes, in unexpected behavior, the OpenEx () method throws an system.accessviolationexception and the program stop, I can't clear the file that the program is trying to open and canot cancel the requst to open and move on.

I can catch the exception, but once it happens with a particular file then also trying to open all the following files throws an exception.
I would like to ask:
1. Why does this sometimes happen inconsistently?
2. Is there a way to cancel the file opening request? Does memory need / can be cleared? What do I need to do so that I can open files after it happens with some file?

This is the main code:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Documents.OpenEx(currVisioFile,(int)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenRW);
```

Comment: Why do you need to open all these files for _from a Visio add-in_ ? It doesn't answer your question, but you could maybe make the request to open files with Visio from an external application like Python using the win32com layer?

Comment: I must to open the file from VSTO Add-Id because is already exist and run a lot of operations on each file. Thousands of lines of code.
@CorentinPane

Comment: well you could open Visio from an external script and let the Visio add-in work from here, then close Visio from the external script and open it again with the next file etc

Comment: @CorentinPane
What are you actually telling me?
Need for each file to open and close Visio?
Can't I use the same instance of Visio that opens and closes different files?

Comment: When Visio instance gets stuck when opening or closing a file, is there a way to reset that instance from the opening or closing request?

Comment: I posted an answer with details :) hopefully that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If opening a lot of files from the Visio add-in itself is or becomes unstable (issue I've been facing as well), I recommend opening and closing a new instance of Visio for each document you have.

A way to do that in Python for example is to install the `pypiwin32` package and then run the following script:

```py
import win32com.client

documentsToProcess = ["path/to/doc1", "path/to/doc2", "path/to/doc3"]

for path in documentsToProcess:
    app = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Visio.Application") # Open new Visio instance
    doc = app.Documents.Open(path) # Open your document (and hopefully blocks)
    doc.Saved = true # For quiet exit
    app.Quit()
```

You can find all official documentation about the Open function and all others objects and methods [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.documents.open).

Then you would change your add-in code so that it just waits for a document to be opened before processing it, like this:

```cs
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    // We subscribe to the DocumentOpened/Created event
    this.Application.DocumentOpened += Application_DocumentOpened;
}

private void Application_DocumentOpened(Document doc) {
    // Process your document here.
    // Do your work on your document here!
}
```

Usually the work you have to do on each document is much longer than just creating a new instance of Visio so it shouldn't be an issue.

Maybe you need to make a few changes to ensure that the Visio instance closes correctly but that's the idea. You could also force kill the process if needed when it gets stuck.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your detailed and invested answer!

To make sure, are you saying that a Visio instance becomes unstable when opening and closing several documents in that instance regardless of my code?

Assuming this is true and not because of something bad in my code that causes Visio to crash,
Do I have to open Visio from an external location to AddIn?
It's really not good for me and will make me change lots of code.

Comment: After all, I can catch the exception,
Is there any way to stabilize the same Visio instance somehow? Delete cache or something?
Can't open a new instance and close the old one from the AddIn code?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to stabilize it. I've just experienced similar stability issues when opening files from within the addin. Maybe the stability issue comes from your code, but then opening a new Visio instance everytime will probably fix the issue, or at least hide it.... I would have loved to answer you by saying "you need to make this and that to stabilize Visio" but having worked a lot with Visio addins, I know it's not that easy :p

Comment: Can i create new instance in addition to the first one, processing the file, closing the instance and so on? create new instance->Processing file->closing instance?

Comment: You mean opening multiple instances of VIsio in parallel? Yes, it is possible using the `DispatchEx` method I've shown. It will open a new instance everytime it's called.